# Dynamically load AppleScripts relative to current script's location

Tags: applescript

I would like to be able to reference a model file that is located in the same directory as the controller.

Initially, they are located in the project's root folder, but when they are compiled (using `osacompile`) they both will be located in `Controller.scptd/Contents/Resources/Scripts` directory.

Controller.applescript:

```
property path :  (container of (path to me) as text) <-- Error: Can’t make container of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:craig:Projects:AppleScript:Foobar:Controller.applescript" into type text.
property model : load script file (path & "Model.scpt")
```

I can't get the syntax working correctly; I've been unable to find a workable solution.  Is there a way to get this working?

** edit **

As noted by @dj-bazzie-wazzie and @mklement0, `path to me` in the context of an application bundle refers to the script bundle (`Controller.scptd` in my example), not to the script itself (`Controller.scptd/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt`).

Assuming that `Model.scpt` has been bundled with `main.scpt` in the `/Contents/Resources/Scripts` directory, this syntax works:

```
set Model to load script (path to resource "Model.scpt" in directory "Scripts")
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with non-bundled scripts; @Michele-Percich's solution will work, however.

Is there a single syntax that work work in both situations?

Comment: It is implied by @dj bazzie wazzie's answer, but to make it explicit: in a script _bundle_, `path to me` refers to the _bundle folder_, not `main.scpt` _inside_ the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the requirement added later that the code should work in *both* the following scenarios:

- When running as simple `*.scpt` *file*: load the other script from *same* folder (as the running script itself)
- When running as `*.scptd` *bundle*: load the other script from the *bundle* (technically, the same folder as the main script inside the bundle).

This solution builds on the helpful answers provided by [@Michele Percich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323337/45375) and [@dj bazzie wazzie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24327727/45375); [@dj bazzie wazzie's great tutorial on script libraries](http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=41638) is well worth a read.

```applescript
set otherScript to "Model.scpt"
if (path to me as string) ends with ":" then # Running as bundle?
    set otherScript to ¬
        (path to resource otherScript in directory "Scripts") as string
else
    tell application "Finder" to set otherScript to ¬
        (container of (path to me) as string) & otherScript
end if

set model to load script file otherScript
```

`path to me as string`ending in `:` implies that the path is a *folder*. Since `path to me` returns the bundle *folder* when running as a script bundle (AppleScript-based `*.app` bundles do the same), we can deduce that the running code is part of a bundle.

Answer (score 4):

Properties are initialized (set) at compile time and their values are persistent. So even if you have dynamic values in there, the script will only keep the value of the command/class when it the script was compiled for the last time. Here an example of how properties work:

```
property a : current date
return a
```

You can keep clicking the run button in AppleScript-Editor but you'll see that the date isn't updated. This is because when the script compiles, the compiler noticed `current date` and uses its value. It's not a reference to `current date` that is stored into the property, but the value returned by `current date` at compile time, which is just a date value.

You just need to load the script every time when the script is launched.

```
property model : missing value
set model to load script file ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Scripts:Model.scpt")
```

EDIT: Update my answer after the question's has beeing updated

If you want to make use of libraries inside and outside library bundles I would take a look at script libraries, if you're running Mavericks. When you're using the use statement to load a script library and the running script is a bundle (saved as application or script bundle) it will first tries to load the library from there. If fails or the script is just an file and not a bundle it will load the script library from the 4 library folders (user, computer, network, system library and in that order).

I have written [a tutorial about how to write script libraries](http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=41638)

Comment: +1 for the explanation of property initialization. The script-loading command could be simplified to: `set model to load script file (path to resource "Model.scpt" in directory "Scripts") as string`

Answer (score 3):

`container` is a Finder's element.
Also, why are you using properties?

Anyway, this should work:

```applescript
tell application "Finder"
   set myPath to container of (path to me) as text
end tell
set model to load script file (myPath & "Model.scpt")
```